# How to scroll a widget inside a SingleChildScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, scroll, widget

I have pdf viewer inside the SingleChildScrollView. Pdf viewer does not scroll only Column does. How do I make it that Column will be able to scroll and also the pdf will be able to scroll?

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Nahranie súboru'),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
               child: SfPdfViewer.file(file), 
               height: 200, 
               width: double.infinity
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const PayRadioGroup(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const PayList(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => uploadData(),
                  child: const Text('Odoslať Dáta'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without a sized box for the pdf.

```dart
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Nahranie súboru'),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
               SfPdfViewer.file(file), 
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const PayRadioGroup(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const PayList(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => uploadData(),
                  child: const Text('Odoslať Dáta'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
       ),
      );
```

Comment: Without the SizedBox it throws an error. RenderBox was not laid out.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I just implemented a scroll bar to the pdf viewer. Thank you for responding.